# How do we display a certain category type on a page while hiding all others?

Tags: posts, functions, categories

We need to hide a specific category type on all pages but one, and then display that hidden category on a singular page.

So far, to hide the category on all pages, we have coded this:

```
// Exclude Category Posts from Home Page
    function themeprefix_exclude_category( $query ) {
        if ( $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-3' );//add your category number
        }
        return $query;
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'themeprefix_exclude_category' );
```

We have found this code to display only a certain post category, but it does not work for a specific page.

```
// Only Portfolio Category
    function only_portfolio_category( $query ) {
       if ( $query->is_page('clinical-trials') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
       $query->set( 'cat', '3' );
       }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'only_portfolio_category' );
```

If anyone has a workaround for this, we'd love to know!

Answer (score -1):

Try this using is_single and query_vars rather than is_page:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_queries', 1000 );

function change_queries ($query){
    if(is_single() && $query->query_vars['page_id']== 'your page id'){
        $query->set( 'cat', '3' );
    }
}
```